# generator of ideal in ring of fraction

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Z[1/17] is subring of Q consisting all fractions whose denominator is a power of 17.
Every ideal of Z[1/17] is generate by an element of the form n/1, n belong to Z.
Find the generator of ideal <4/17^8> as a smallest positive n such that n/1 generate the ideal.
why the generator of the ideal can be expressed as n/1?
I don’t really know how to approach the problem

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

It's just $n=4$, because the ideals $(4)$ and $\big(\frac4{17^8}\big)$ contain each other, since $\frac1{17^8}\in\Bbb Z[\frac1{17}]$.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but for the ideal <15/17^7, 6/17^7>, why the generator for this ideal is not 3?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be $3$?